# Used boolean modifier for lettering on 3D print. It won't print letters, but shows as working

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I am trying to print this piece I made. It looks as though everything is right until I put in in my print program and the lettering doesn't print right. I can't figure out what I did wrong.

[image][image]

File before the Boolean

[image]

[image]

[image]

I got it to the point of showing letters, but they are outlined. How do I make it solid?

Comment: Try different file format. I bet .stl will manage to transfer all data correctly. If not, try to import the file to FreeCAD or MeshLab, and export it in different acceptable file formats. In general there is nothing wrong with the mesh itself so it has to be file conversion problem.

Comment: The geometry under the discrete letters looks quite strange. I would create one mesh out of two submeshes. One for the scoreboard, one for the lettering. AFAIK they don't need to be connected.

Comment: I exported as stl. I also left the text as a mesh and the score panel as a mesh and selected both and exported. I got letters when exported but they were just outlined and not solid. I did use the solidify modifier

Comment: The issue is most likely caused by the walls of the letters being bigger than 2 but smaller than 3 lines thick. Imagine printing a wall with a thickness of 2.5 lines, the slicer will try to keep the original dimensions so you will end up with 2 lines and an empty space the size of half a line in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Try with file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7t43CPM6VA-RURVZDg0NGhuTEk/view?usp=sharing (I'll delete it from my drive at Oct 28).

I did the following:

1. Converted text to mesh.
2. Combined all text meshes together.
3. Extruded text meshes on Z axis.
4. Did the boolean modifier to carve the plate.
5. Applied the modifier to the plate.
6. Deleted the text meshes.
7. Exported to STL.

Comment: Thanks for the help but... Imported the stl file to simplify 3D. I was going for extruded text 1mm out and not in. When I make the text go in I get the same result as you did

Comment: i'll do the extrusion out then

Comment: try with this one:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7t43CPM6VA-enNteWl0dU5oMVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I added a picture above. After working it a bit and trying different methods I got it to do the lettering and did a print... but yours is still doing the same as mine. It is outlining the lettering instead of being solid lettering,